# How come Mimic needs glasses like Cyclops?

Tags: marvel, x-men

I've been a humongous fan of the X-Men for years, however Mimic is, by far one of my favorite (second only to Toad, but different story) X-Men baddies. Yet, there is one thing I find deeply disturbing.

Mimic's powers are those of the original five X-Men (Cyclops, Iceman, The Angel, The Beast, & Marvel-Girl), giving him the following powers: optic blasts from the eyes, cryokinesis (freezing), wings that enable flight, enhanced strength, and telekinesis. Now, the deeply disturbing part? Cyclops' optic blasts. Due to a severe head trauma in his childhood, Cyclops must wear a pair of ruby-quartz lenses to block a never-ending flow of optic energy which would annihilate everything in it's path.

Now, when Calvin Rankin (Mimic) copies that power, the beam is STILL unstable and Calvin finds himself wearing a similar pair of glasses to block the beam. Now, at first, this is acceptable, since it was before the revelation of Scott's head trauma. However, after the head trauma was revealed, Mimic still needed to block the beam. Why? If Mimic copied the power and had not received trauma to the head, he should be able to use the beam freely, am I right?

If anyone has any information whatsoever on this particular matter, it would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: “deeply disturbing” — really? Interesting priorities.

Comment: @PaulD.Waite-I just got home and got a chance to check out my Mimic question for the first time to see if there were any answers. Granted there was an answer (P.S. thanks, Sean Duggan; big help), but what really caught my eye was your 'interesting priorities' comment. Not trying to be a d**k, but next time, try being a tad bit more polite in future posts, as I was VERY offended, and do not wish to see others offended by similar comments. Have a pleasant evening.

Comment: sure, sorry I offended you. I meant that “deeply disturbing” seems like a surprisingly strong reaction to the details of Mimic’s powers. But you’re quite right, your reactions are your business, and not mine.

Comment: @PaulD.Waite-Thank you for the apology; it is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

It all depends on how you interpret Mimic's abilities. One way is that he somehow copies the overall effects of the beam power as if he'd been affected by that X-gene and he either gains intuitive usage of it or has since figured it out. In that case, no, he should not have any trouble stopping the beam.

However, what if he instead copied the general physical state that generates the powers? In that case, he may have copied whatever brain damage Cyclops had, resulting in the lack of control. This overlaps with a third possibility, that he copies the X-gene's effects, but gains the knowledge of how to control them from his target via some sort of low-level intuitive mental power. He can't control the beams because he never picked up the knack from Cyclops of learning how to turn them off. And if he's never learned that the lack of control was due to brain damage, he may have never thought to try to figure out how to turn it off since he's never recopied the ability.

That is, of course, assuming that he lacks control. His Wikipedia article states that "because he lacks Cyclops' brain damage, Mimic is able to control [the eyebeams]".

Comment: Rogue is the same. She can't control Scott powers cause she gains his memories too

Comment: @Toadx23:
Is there anything more I can add to my answer to improve it?